# Why "scanf" works but fgets doesn't works in C?

Tags: c

Look here, those two programms should be equivalent in my opinion. But obviously they aren't, as the first programm works and the second doesn't. Can someone explain to me, why fgets() doesn't do the job?

```
// FIRST PROGRAM : WORKS FINE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *stream;
    char fileName[67];
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    printf("%s", fileName);
    stream = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char ch;
    if(stream){
        ch = fgetc(stream);
        while(!feof(stream)){
            putchar(ch);
            ch = fgetc(stream);
        }
        fclose(stream);
    }
}


// SECOND PROGRAM: DOES NOT WORK 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *stream;
    char fileName[67];
    fgets(fileName, 67, stdin);
    printf("%s", fileName);
    stream = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char ch;
    if(stream){
        ch = fgetc(stream);
        while(!feof(stream)){
            putchar(ch);
            ch = fgetc(stream);
        }
        fclose(stream);
    }
}
```

I enter "test.txt" into the console both times and press enter then. Of course test.txt exists in the right directory

Comment: `fgets()` retains the `newline` entered, please remove it.

Comment: What does "the second program does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: ... you can check this by changing your print statement to `printf("[%s]", dateiname);` then you can see the `newline` is there.

Comment: means i enter "test.txt" and the first block of code will open and read whatever is in test.txt und the second block will just do nothing

Comment: Thanks to Weather Vane (thank you! ) i can see, that fgets() adds a new line to the filename. Can you tell me how to avoid that fgets() adds the new line, althought its nessecary pressing the enter button to confirm the text entered?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `fgets()` retains the `newline` entered. You can verify it is there by altering your print statement to

```
printf("[%s]", filename);
```

when the `]` will appear on the next line. You can remove the  trailing `newline` like this

```
#include <string.h>

...

filename [ strcspn(filename, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Mister Vane, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @Weather Vane: I think you are right with your diagnosis of the problem but I am not so sure about your suggested cure! Have you considered what happens if your `strcspn()` trick is applied to a string which does _not_ contain a CRLF? (Or indeed if the line terminator is not `\r\n` on the OP's system?)

Comment: @AAT it is completely safe. If not found, the string length is returned, so it overwrites the existing terminator.

Comment: @AAT the `newline` does not have to be both of those. Any match will do, now please read the man page for `strcspn`, it is *not* `strstr()`!!

Comment: @WeatherVane - many apologies, you are quite right! I was indeed thinking about `strstr()` and I should have read the man page (or MSDN) first. I am happy to fully endorse your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you experienced is correctly solved by Weather Vane, but I want to point another problem with your code:  the loops for reading and writing the contents of the file are incorrect.  Testing the end of file with `feof(stream)` leads to incorrect behaviour most of the time. In your case, a read error from `stream` will cause your program to loop endlessly, writing `0xFF` bytes to `stdout`.

There is a much simpler and idiomatic way to implement this loop:

```
if (stream) {
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(stream);
}
```

As you can see, it is simpler and correctly tests for `EOF` at the right time, when input fails.  It stores the return value of `fgetc()` into an `int` variable capable of holding all possible return values from `fgetc()`.  Using an `int` is necessary because comparing a `char` value to `EOF` either always fails if the `char` type is unsigned or potentially gives false positives if `char` is signed and has value `'\377'`.

Comment: i thank you for correcting my code. i am stunned somehow, as i have found the feof(stream) -way to solve the task in a computer science book that is used at my university. I do not yet get the full picture of the problem that you describe but the code you wrote works with my programm and i am glad that you shared this with me!

Comment: This was one of those rare occasions where `feof()` was being used correctly, checking *after* the file read and not *before*, but you are right about detecting errors, which are flagged by the `EOF` from `fgetc()`

Comment: @Weather Vane: that's what I meant by *most of the time*.  Just like `strncpy`, `feof` is almost never the right tool for the job.  `scanf` is next on the list of mostly misused C library functions.